# Do I need to convert ascii to uint8_t to write and display over uart (putty)

Tags: c, function, ascii, uart

I've a sensor connected on UART to an mcu. The sensor outputs ascii characters. Below are my functions to read from the uart (the sensor) and write from the uart (to my computer over putty).

My question is, do I need to convert the ascii characters to be of type `uint8_t` to write over the uart as that is what putchar() requires? There is noting being displayed in putty.

Comment: You're not checking the return code of getch(), are you sure its not returning -1? Is there a way to debug that, maybe toggle an LED?

Comment: `return ((int) c);` - the cast is useless, as you already return `int`. Every cast weakens the alread weak type checking in C. So general advise is to cast only iff 1) The cast is necessary 2) You understand **all** implications of the cast and 3) accept them **fully**.

Answer (score 1):

The type `uint8_t` is a typedef of `unsigned char`, and it is required to have the same layout as a `signed char` or a plain `char`.

So, you can freely cast between `uint8_t` and `char` or between `uint8_t*` and `char*`, and everything will just work.

However, you cannot cast between `int*` and `uint8_t*`, because the base types will be of different size.

My advice would be to write something like:

```
void putcchar(uint8_t c) {
  ti_uart_write_buffer(TI_UART_0, &c, 1);
}
```

And then call it directly:

```
int l = getch();
putcchar(l);
```

Note that `getch()` returns an `int` instead of a `char` just to be able to return `EOF`, so the cast to `char` will be safe *unless* it is `EOF`. You may want to add:

```
int l = getch();
if (l == EOF) break;
putcchar(l);
```

This is true as long as you consider your `char/uint8_t` values as binary bytes or ASCII characters. If you happen to have a non ASCII characters (e.g. `'é'`) then you'd need to consider the character encoding.

**PS**: I'm assuming you are using a *normal* architecture for your program, that is the byte is 8 bits long and the character encoding is ASCII based. Since you are using Putty, you are probably on MS-Windows, so I'm pretty safe here.